# How does mutual information equal $I(x;y)=\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)log(\frac{p(x|y)}{p(x)})$

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

**How does mutual information equal $I(x;y)=\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)log(\frac{p(x|y)}{p(x)})$?**

So the definition for mutual information I'm familiar with is $I(X;Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y)$.

Where $H(X)=-\sum_{x\in X}p(x)logp(x)$ and $H(X|Y)=-\sum_{x\in X, y\in Y}p(y)p(x|y)logp(x|y)$

I can see that $p(y)p(x|y)=p(x,y)$, but I'm not sure what eliminates $p(x)$ from $H(X)$ and how $logp(x|y)$ from $H(X|Y)$ and $logp(x)$ from $H(X)$ results in $log\frac{p(x|y)}{p(x)}$, because $logp(x)$
is summed over $X$,while $logp(x|y)$ is summed over $X$ and $Y$.

I'm not sure how they ends up deriving into $I(x;y)=\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)log(\frac{p(x|y)}{p(x)})$?

Comment: What are *your* definitions of $H(X)$ and $H(X\mid Y)$?  According to some definitions the formula for $I$ is an easy algebraic step from those definitions, suggesting the details of your definition are important.

Comment: @whuber sorry I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition
$$
I(X; Y) = KL(p(x, y)||p(x)p(y)) = \sum_{x,y}p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x, y)}{p(x) p(y)}
$$

Note $p(x,y) = p(y)p(x|y)$, and the $p(y)$-s in the numerator and denominator will cancel to give you the expression you're after.

Comment: This leads to another question I have now that I see the mutual information equation in this form with a KL divergence. What exactly is the KL divergence between the joint and the product of the marginals provide about x and y information wise? Or about p(x,y) and p(x)p(y). Because KL divergence usually signifies a distance so to speak (not exactly) between 2 distributions. In what way is knowing the distance between the marginal products and the joint useful?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can think of the MI as a measure of dependence. If X and Y are independent then $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$ which implies the KL is 0 and hence the MI. Conversely, if the X and Y are somehow associated (linearly or otherwise), the $KL>0$. Does that provide some intuition?

Comment: O I see. Sorry for the obscurity I guess what would help me is an example use case of this where knowing the measure of dependence is useful. Because the way it's being used in the paper I referenced in the original post to account for how much similar information is between 2 inputs of data that is relevant for a task. Which feels different from dependence between the 2 inputs of data, which are the inputs to the MI formula.